# Eloquent where clause not taking associative array

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, where-clause, associative-array

I'm trying to pass an associative array to a where clause using eloquent, but I am getting an error.

Here is a sample of what I am passing

```
$where_array = [
       'last_name' => 'Smith',
       'first_name' => 'John'
];

$match = MyClass::where($where_array)->get();
```

This returns an error like:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   '{\"last_name\":\"Smith\",\"first_name\":\"John\"}' in 'where clause'
>   (SQL: select * from `my_class` where
>   `{\"last_name\":\"Smith\",\"first_name\":\"John\"}` is null and
>   `my_class`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)",
>       "exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",
>       "file": "/home/vagrant/code/unity/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
>       "line": 669,

I don't know why it's not taking the array or why it's checking if it's null. Is there some library I'm not including that makes this format work? Why does it have the Object {} brackets in the query? Is it getting turned into an object somewhere/somehow?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, the correct format to pass multiple where arguments is the following:

> You may also pass an array of conditions to the where function:
>
> $users = DB::table('users')->where([
>       ['status', '=', '1'],
>       ['subscribed', '<>', '1'], ])->get();

in your case you need to change your code to:

```
$where_array = [
       ['last_name' ,'=', 'Smith'],
       ['first_name' ,'=', 'John'],
];

$match = MyClass::where($where_array)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, in where clause you need to pass at least  2 arguments, the first one is the name of the column in your model that you want to apply your condition.

for example:
I want to find a user in users table with name 'hossein'.

```
$user = User::where('name','hossein')->first();
```